# i have linked external javascript in head section still when i call the functions it says undefined function error

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I am trying to resolve this undefined function error issue but still it is giving error i used direct javascript code directly in head section in a script tag but still it is giving me the same error. i have also tried this in the body tag but still giving same error.

This is the Html  code from where im calling function on button click. i have imported the javascript in the head section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>add jokes</title>
        <style>


                        #logout
                               {
                                 width: 80px;
                                 margin-left: 27%;
                                 margin-top: 0%;
                               }

            #jokesform, #resetform, #signupform
                                {
                                    display: none;
                                }
            #logout
                {
                    position: fixed;
                    self-align: right;
                }

            input
                {
                    width: 98.5%;
                    height: 37px;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                }
            select
                {
                    width: 99%;
                    height: 37px;
                    
                }
            button
                {
                    width: 99%;    
                    height: 40px;
                    background-color: #f0a000;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                }
            .formcontainer
                {
                    text-align: center;
                }
            label
                {
                    font-size: 25px;
                }
            textarea
                {
                    width: 98.5%;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                    height: 200px;
                }           
        </style>

<!--- here i have imorted the javascript --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addjokesfunctions.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body class="card" >
        <button id="logout" onclick=logout()>Logout</button>
    
        <div id="loginform" class="formcontainer card-body">
            <h1 class="card-header">login form</h1><hr/><br/>
            <label for="loginemail">Email Id</label>
            <input id="loginemail" type="email" name="email">
            <br/>
            <label for="loginpassword">Password</label>
            <input id="loginpassword" type="password" name="password">
            <br/>
            <button type="button" onclick=login()>Login</button>
            <a href=# onclick=showsignupform()>Signup</a>
            <a href=# onclick=showforgotpasswordform()>forgot password</a>
        </div>
        <div id="signupform" class="formcontainer card-body">
            <h1 class="card-header">signup form</h1><hr/><br/>
            <label for="signupemail">Email Id</label>
            <input id="signupemail" type="email" name="email">
            <br/>
            <label for="signuppassword">Password</label>
            <input id="signuppassword" type="text" name="password">
            <br/>
            <label for="signupconfirmpassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input id="signupconfirmpassword" type="text" name="confirmpassword">
            <br/>
            <button type="button" onclick=signup()>Signup</button>
        </div>
        <div id="resetform" class="formcontainer card-body">
            <h1 class="card-header">reset form</h1><hr/><br/>
            <label for="resetformemail">Email Id</label>
            <input id="resetformemail" type="email" name="email">
            <br/>           
            <button type="button" onclick=reset()>Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div id="jokesform" class="formcontainer card-body">
            <h1 class="card-header">jokes form</h1><hr/><br/>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name">
            <label for="joketitle">Joke Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="joketitle">
            <label for="jokecategory">Joke Category</label>
            <select id="jokecategory">
                <option>Santa Banta</option>
                <option>Drinker</option>
                <option>Politics</option>
                <option>Friends</option>
                <option>Husband Wife</option>
                <option>Celebrity</option>
                <option>Life</option>
                <option>School</option>
                <option>College</option>
                <option>Teacher Student</option>
                <option>Doctor</option>
                <option>Pappu</option>
                <option>Gyan</option>
                <option>Aajkal k Log</option>
                <option>Aajkal k Ladka Ladki</option>
                <option>Maa Beta</option>
                <option>Baap Beta</option>
            </select>
            <label for="joketext">Joke</label>
            <textarea id="joketext"></textarea>
            <button type=button onclick=postjoke()>Post joke</button>
        </div>







    </body>


</html>
```

this is the javascript code that contains the function to be called.

```
//addjokesfunctions.js
// add jokes.html javascript functions code

function logout()
{
    firebase.auth().signOut(). then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
}




firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    document.getElementById("jokesform").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("signupform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("resetform").style.display = "none";    
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    document.getElementById("jokesform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("signupform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("resetform").style.display = "none";
  }
});


function showsignupform()
{
    document.getElementById("jokesform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("signupform").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("resetform").style.display = "none";
}

function showforgotpasswordform()
{
    document.getElementById("jokesform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("signupform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("resetform").style.display = "block";
}

function login()
{
    email = document.getElementById("loginemail").value;
    password = document.getElementById("loginpassword").value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    alert("error code : "+ errorCode + " error message : "+ errorMessage);
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
}

function signup()
{
    email = document.getElementById("signupemail").value;
    password = document.getElementById("signuppassword").value;
    confirmpassword = document.getElementById("signupconfirmpassword").value;

    if(password.localeCompare(confirmpassword)==0)
    {
        alert("you will get confirmation email if information given by you is right");
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
 final FirebaseUser User = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        User.sendEmailVerification();

alert("verification email sent");

    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
    alert("error code : "+ errorCode + " error message : " + errorMessage);
  });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("password and confirm password doesnot match");
        document.getElementById("signuppassword").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("signupconfirmpassword").style.borderColor = "red";
    }
}

function reset()
{
    email = document.getElementById("resetformemail").value;
    
    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(function() {
  // Email sent.
    alert(" password reset email sent");
    
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
    errorCode = error.code;
    errorMessage = error.message;
    alert("error code : " + errorCode + " error message : " + errorMessage); 
});
    
}

function postjoke()
{
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
        postername = document.getElementById("name").value;
        joketitle = document.getElementById("joketitle").value;
        jokecategory = document.getElementById("jokecategory").value;
        joketext = document.getElementById("joketext");
        
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
      {

       alert(this.responseText);

      // alert("response");
      }
    };
  xhttp.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request="postername=" + postername + "joketitle=" + joketitle + "jokecategory=" + jokecategory + "joketext=" + joketext + "posteremail=" + user.email;
  xhttp.send(request);




} else {
  // No user is signed in.
    alert("sign in to post joke");
}

}
```

following are errors -

Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifieraddjokesfunctions.js:81:7

Uncaught ReferenceError: showsignupform is not defined
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html:1
add jokes.html:1:1
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: showforgotpasswordform is not defined
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html#:1
add jokes.html:1:1
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html#:1

Uncaught TypeError: logout is not a function
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html#:1
add jokes.html:1:1
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html#:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html#:1
add jokes.html:1:1
onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html#:1

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? What line is it coming from?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: showsignupform is not defined
    onclick file:///home/anupsaha/Downloads/jokesite-master/jokesite by Anup Saha read the readme text file/add jokes.html:1

Comment: Try putting the script element just before the `</body>`?

Comment: Still getting same error   i tried this -<html><head><style>some css</style></head> <body> some html <script type="text/javascript" src="js/addjokesfunctions.js"></script> </body></html>

Comment: If I put your code into a stacksnippet (the `<>` icon) I do not get any errors except for `final FirebaseUser User` which throws a syntax error.

Comment: `final FirebaseUser User` is not valid javascript? Why do you think it should work?

Comment: yes code is working if i remove final FirebaseUser User